# Не работает wildcard в elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

Делаю поиск по тайпу со следующим запросом:

```
{
  "query": {
     "simple_query_string" : {
       "query": "7102001101ED50802004.SFD",
       "analyze_wildcard" : true
    }
  }
}
```

Выдает 40 hits. А если в конце добавляю `*` вместо `.SFD`:

```
 {
      "query": {
         "simple_query_string" : {
           "query": "7102001101ED50802004*",
           "analyze_wildcard" : true
        }
      }
    }
```

... то находит только 1 документ. Как так может быть? Ведь минимум поиск должен был бы выдать те же 40 документов.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первом случае поиск осуществляется с логическим ИЛИ: `7102001101ED50802004` или `SFD`, а во втором ищется только уникальный номер, отсюда и такой результат.